# Possible reorderings for a given set of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have this input:

$x = 1, 2, 3$.

The output should look like:

$x_1 = 1, 2, 3$

$x_2 = 2, 3, 1$

$x_3 = 3, 1, 2$

$x_4 = 2, 1, 3$

$x_5 = 1, 3, 2$

$x_6 = 3, 2, 1$

---

What's this called in mathematics?
What is the formula to know that for 3 elements as an input, the output would be an array of 6 elements? (to apply on +3 elements)
Where can I read more about this?

Comment: Those are the [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the initially specified set.

Comment: first, I thank Mr. Glorfindel for answering and editing my question. For those who downvoted it, with all my respect, thank you! and please consider this Arabic saying : فاقد الشيء لا يعطيه... I'm not supposed to know every thing, but I'm thankfully rational and objective, and sorry if my question doesn't suit your styles... but I belong to here! I hope I clearly explained why my question is relevant to your community. I'm posting -when I'm done- the JS exercise and its solution and teach me how to formulate my future questions based upon it

Answer (score 3):

These are [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

If you have a set of $n$ elements, the number of permutations is $n!$; the ! denotes the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). Basically, you have $n$ choices for the first element, $n-1$ choices for the second (all numbers except for the first element), etc., etc., so the number of permutations is $n \times (n-1) \, \times \, ... \, \times \, 1$.

The Wikipedia article lists several [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations) to generate all permutations of a given set.

Comment: you're great! thank you so much!